# Disable the space button while on IME composition mode

Tags: typescript, input, text, removing-whitespace, ime

In a React TypeScript project, I am trying to disable a text input via the following

```
<TextInput
  onKeyDown={(e) => preventSpaces(e)
  ...props
/>
```

Where as the `preventSpaces` function is as follows

```
const WHITESPACE_CHARS = ['\u{0020}', '\u{00A0}', '\u{2009}', '\u{3000}'];

const preventSpaces = (e: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
  if (WHITESPACE_CHARS.includes(e.key)) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
};
```

This works fine however when I'm typing in the Japanese IME mode, clicking the space bar gives an `e.key` of `Process`. Hence, the space button/a whitespace is not disabled at all.

Comment: It may be better to use `event.code` in your case https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code